# Python asyncio monitoring

Tags: python, monitoring, python-asyncio

I've a python program which are launching a random number of asyncio coroutine. During the time my program can launch new ones and some of them can exit when they have terminated their work.

I would like to know if it's possible to report, every minute, the number of active coroutine?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot *launch a coroutine* but could start a new [task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task)

For retrieving the number of active tasks please use `len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks())`.

**Upd**

Starting from Python 3.7 please use `len(asyncio.all_tasks())` API.

Comment: You're right it's the number of tasks not coroutine, it's still confused for me :(  but you're answer is perfect. Thanks

Comment: Roughly speaking coroutine is an async function but task is async thread.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov What is meant when docs talk about "number of active tasks"? [Look's like](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41029450/4249707) it's simple incremental counter for all executed tasks.

Comment: @ElRuso what docs are you talking about? `Task.all_tasks()` returns a set  of tasks created by the loop. Please note: finished but still not garbage collected tasks are counted.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Tnx, I got answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41039173/4249707). [Doc's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.all_tasks) have not enough examples