# Count active tasks in event loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

How can I find out how many active tasks in the event loop?
In documentation I find only [asyncio.Task.all_tasks()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.all_tasks) but it's simple incremental counter:

```
import asyncio


async def coro():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    tasks = []
    print('Tasks count: ', len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
    for idx in range(3):
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(coro())
        tasks.append(task)
        print('Tasks count: ', len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print('Tasks count: ', len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
Tasks count:  1
Tasks count:  2
Tasks count:  3
Tasks count:  4
Tasks count:  4
```

Expected output:

```
Tasks count:  1
Tasks count:  2
Tasks count:  3
Tasks count:  4
Tasks count:  1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`all_tasks` returns all the registered tasks, including the finished ones. You can simply filter the tasks by `done()` to get the active ones:

```
import asyncio


async def coro():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    tasks = []
    print('Tasks count: ', len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
    for idx in range(3):
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(coro())
        tasks.append(task)
        print('Tasks count: ', len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print('Tasks count: ', len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
    print('Active tasks count: ', len(
        [task for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks() if not task.done()])
    )

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Which outputs:

```
Tasks count:  1
Tasks count:  2
Tasks count:  3
Tasks count:  4
Tasks count:  4
Active tasks count:  1
```

Comment: `print('Active tasks count:', sum(1 for task in asyncio.all_tasks() if task.done()))` won't create a temporary list just to call `len()` with it

Answer (score 18):

In Python 3.7+ there is a `asyncio.all_tasks()` method which returns the unfinished tasks for the current running loop.

So this simplifies to:

`count_active_tasks = len(asyncio.all_tasks())`